# Section header display in Footer Blank Cell in SAP BO 4.1

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

Is it possible to display the Section header to the blank cell in the Footer of the report in SAP BO 4.1 ?

Let me explain the requirement clearly:

- As you all have seen in books you will be able to see the name of the book at the footer of the page. Similarly, here in the report, the selected prompt values for the Section display is to be displayed at the Footer of the page.
- I have tried the following possibilities:

  1. To display the selected Values from the prompt

     ```
     =UserResponse("Enter values for Document ID:")
     ```

     The output is ok for single selection, but on 2 values selection it displays two values in the same cell. But I need like only one value according to the section header.
  2. If I add the Document Id also as one of the section, I am able to get the desired result but it displays only one time at the end of that Section. I need it to be displaced in every page based on Section Header...

Anybody, please help me...

Answer (score 0):

A kind of hack that looks like it might work is to hide the page footer and extend the section down towards the bottom of the page.

Ensure your section is set to show on separate pages.

Then add an empty cell and position it where you want to at the bottom of the section and use whatever formula you want.

I have tested this on WebI XI3.1 and assume it should work on 4.1 too.